# remove and add google map markers dynamically asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, web-applications, google-maps-api-3

I am new to asp.net and Google maps. I want to achieve tracking capability on my asp.net page. I want to create a number of markers and then move them along a path.

Can any one help me understand, how do I do it?

I want google maps to work as AJAX

Comment: Do you have work with the tutorials ?

Comment: I tried, but that involved working on their library, which I guess is not good. Because, I will be enslaved to their limitations. Do you know some good tutorial about google maps and asp in ajax? if yes, plz  let me know.

Answer (score 1):

this can be done in many ways, I will dish out a very easy solution,

1.Your webpage should load a map and add markers representing your assets with an id.
2. Your web page should ping your web server every sec to query for change
3. If your server has a change to report it should reply back with the latest latlon for those ids as a json
4.you can then update the positions of those markers.

If you can implement http push(long polling/websockets) then even better as you will get near realtime updates

This assumes that your web server is being updated by your tracking device.

your webservice should always return the latest position it has for the assets.

Updating your markers(assets) on client side is pretty easy as well,
To 'move' your existing marker, you'll wanna make sure its global and then you can just update its position within the function with something like:

```
marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
```

Comment: Thanks for such a wonderful explaination, but as I am a newbie, I would like to ask something more. How do we assign an id to marker? And once marker is made, How do we either remove it or relocate it?